# Intellij IDEA Ultimate Java EE

Tags: web, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have a tiny problem. I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for Java Web. Next my step is download and install **Server TomCat**.
In tutorials they **go Run/Debug Configuration**, press add
and chose **Server TomCat**. So, my problem is the lack of **Server TomCat** in the list.

[image]

I know the problem is so stupid, but I need help.
I use IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Settings/Preferences dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).
2. In the left-hand part of the dialog, select Plugins.
3. In the right-hand part of the dialog, on the Plugins page, type the
   server name of interest (e.g. Tomcat) in the search box. As a result,
   only the plugins whose names and descriptions contain the typed text
   are shown in the list of plugins.
4. If the checkbox to the right of the plugin name is not selected,
   select it.
5. Click OK in the Settings dialog.
6. If suggested, restart IntelliJ IDEA.